# ajax Loading Internal Links into custom Div (not working)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I created a custom jquery/ajax script to direct my links with the class of "navMenu" to load into the div with an ID of "main". I have attached that js to the index page header with the rest of my important css and javascript and jquery files. for all the linked pages will be using the files.  Now that I have finished designing and constructing my main loading page for my website. the button links that I have created will not load to the div i specified in my ajax script. How do I get all links on all pages to load into the specified div with the id of "main". I have accomplished this with the menu. It works flawlessly, but when I click the button links inside of the loaded page (home.php) the will not open in the div and shows that the page is not on the server. please help
Heres a live link to the website https://www.trillumonopoly.com

Here is My Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#main').load('pages/home.php');

     $('.navMenu').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    }); 
`     `});
```

Heres the index pages mock up:

```
<html>
<head>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-108738796-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-108738796-1');
</script>

<title> ILLUMONOPOLY </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon1.png" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>
  <script>
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(["init", {
      appId: "14306e53-45e7-443c-a414-894b84cbac7d",
      autoRegister: false,
      notifyButton: {
        enable: true /* Set to false to hide */
      }
    }]);
  </script>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 600 12px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #666666;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
}

.content {
  background: #666666;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.content.isOpen {
  transform: translate3d(220px,0,0);
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:before {
  content: '\f00a';
  font: 22px fontawesome;
}

/* Demo Navigation */

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
   line-height: 28px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  background: #2a2a2a;
}




</style>
<style>

nav2 {
    height:28px!important;
   align-items: center;
}

ul{ list-style-type: none;} 

@font-face {
    font-family: 'steelfish';
    src: url('fonts/steelfish.ttf');
    font-weight: 200;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Incognito';
    src: url('fonts/Incognito.ttf');
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'round';
    src: url('fonts/Round.ttf');
    font-weight: 100;

}

body{
    font-family: steelfish !important; 
    color: white; !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-size: 17px!Important;
}

h1{
    font-family: Incognito !important; 
    color: white; !important;   
}

h2{
    font-family: round !important; 
    color: white; !important;   
    font-size: 85% !important;
}

.box { border-radius:8px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ffffff;
border-width: 2px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
background-attachment: fixed;
}

.contentX {
    background-image: url("img/bgr.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#main {   
    width:100%;   
    height:93%;    
    overflow:auto !important; 
    overflow-x:hidden !important;   

.scrollbox {
    overflow-y: scroll !important; 
    overflow-x: hidden;


}   

}  
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,250,250,.9); 
  border-radius: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(212,175,55,0.8);
}

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullwidthAudioPlayer.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/lity.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajaxlinks.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.snipcart.com/scripts/2.0/snipcart.js" data-api-key="ZjM1NDE3NDUtZmZhMS00ODA3LWE3ZGUtYzk0MWYwNzRmYjIxNjM2NDQ0NzA2MzQ3Njg0NDY0" id="snipcart"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/2.0/base/snipcart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/lity.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu_cornermorph.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fullwidthaudioplayer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').toggleClass('isOpen');
  });
});
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="title">
     <center><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" height="150" width="150"><h1>Menu</h1></center>
    </div>
                    <div class="link-list container-fluid">
                        <center> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary snipcart-user-profile col-6" style="background-color:#DAA520"><span class="snipcart-user-email">Login</span></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-6" style="background-color:#DAA520"><span class="snipcart-user-logout">LogOut</span></button>
                        </div>

                        <ul id="navMenu"><h2>
                        <li><a href="home" class="navMenu"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="artist" class="navMenu"><span>Talent</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="services"  class="navMenu"><span>Services</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="music" class="navMenu"><span>Music</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="shop" class="navMenu"><span>Beats</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="media" class="navMenu"><span>Videos</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="media" class="navMenu"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact" class="navMenu"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
                        </ul></h2>
                        <br>
                        FOLLOW US
                        </center>
                    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content isOpen">
    <div class="XcontentX">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark nav2" style="background-color:#202020">
          <a class="navbar-brand button" href="#"></a>
         <button type="button" class="badge badge-warning snipcart-checkout" style="background-color:#DAA520"><img src="img/cart.png" height="25" width="25">:<span class="snipcart-total-price"></span></span></button>
        </nav>
        <div id="main"></div>





  </div>
</div> 
</div>


<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom" style="background-color:#202020">
            <div id="fap"></div>
        </nav>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fap').fullwidthAudioPlayer({wrapperColor: '#202020', fillColor: '#ffffff'});
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Heres the HTML mock up from the home.php(initial loading page inside of the div)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>


<script src="js/better-simple-slideshow.min.js"></script>
<style>
.mixingservice {
    background : url("img/parallaxstudio.jpg") repeat fixed 100%;
     background-size: cover;

} 
.general {
    background : url("img/parallaxmain1.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}
.distribution {
    background : url("img/parallaxdistribution.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}
.webdesign {
    background : url("img/webservice.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}
.featuredmusic {
    background : url("img/featured.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Promo Banners -->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" height="400px">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="img-fluid " src="img/banner101.jpg"  height="590px" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/digigodbanner.jpg"  height="590px" alt="DigiGod slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/banner2.jpg"  height="590px" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>
<center>
<!-- Service Banners -->

<div class="general row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" height="420" width="420"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <h1> <font color="white">ILLUMONOPOLY</font></h1><hr style="background-color:#ffffff">
        <div class="box"><br> <font size="6vh">
            Welcome to the official website of ILLUMONOPOLY. The Digital Media cartel. Providing independent businesses and musicians with marketable web media solutions to expand there brands for over 10 years. 
            Its Not what can we do for you. Its more of what cant we do for you. With our dedicated team and staff we can help you evolve your brand to the next level. Let Us Expand Your Brand, Your Sound, Your Visual Production, Your fanbase, Your Social media & web presence.<br><B>LET US HELP YOU EXPAND YOUR BRAND!!!!</b>
            </font>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

        <div class="featuredmusic row"> 

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
                        Featured album cover #2 <hr style="background-color:#ffffff">Bunch of fucckin bullshit that goes heremore bullshit and bullshit<br>Button
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
                        Featured album cover #2 <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>Bunch of fucckin bullshit that goes here<br>more bullshit and bullshit<br>Button
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
                        Featured album cover #2 <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>Bunch of fucckin bullshit that goes here<br>more bullshit and bullshit<br>Button
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 box">
                        Featured album cover #2 <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>Bunch of fucckin bullshit that goes here<br>more bullshit and bullshit<br>Button
                    </div>

        </div>
        <div class="mixingservice row">
            <div class="col-6">

            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="img/mixservice.png" class="img-fluid">
                    <br>
                <H1>CLIENTS</H1><hr style="background-color:#ffffff">
                <font size="6vh">Tory Lanes, Ron Browz, 2 Chainz, J-Hard 360, Dezzy Chamberland, Sig Music, ZaeTheGodd and more....<br>
                        </font><br>


                        <a href="services" class="navMenu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="background-color:"red" >Order Now</button></a>

                        <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="general row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <center><br><br>
                        <h1><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" height="100" width="100"> expanding brands for the Last decade</h1>
                        <br><br>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="distribution row">  
            <div class="col-6">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/iphone.png" height="500" width="360">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6" style="padding-top: 30px;  padding-bottom: 30px;">
                    <img src="img/distrotext2.png" class="img-fluid">
                    <br>
                    <img src="img/streams.png" class="img-fluid">
                    <br><br><a href="services" class="navMenu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color:#000000">Sign Up</button></a>
                    <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="webdesign row"><br><br><Br>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                        <img src="img/mactop.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><br><Br><Br>
                <div class="container-fluid box">
                        <font color="red" size="5vh"><h2>Web & Application Developement  </h2><br></font>

                         <h2>Are You In Need of a Website? And or an Mobile Application? <br>
                         Our Team of developers can get your brand up and running and designed to your specifications in just a week.
                         Inquire via email for questions and quotes for custom designs and scripts, websites and applications. 
                         <br>No JOB TOO BIG NO JOB TOO SMALL. LET US EXPAND YOUR BRAND!!!!!<br></h2><br><br>
                         <a href="services" class="navMenu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color:#666666">Inquire Now</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>      


        </div>
<h1>Testing this here</h1>

<!-- Google Ads & Scripts -->
<br><br>
<br>
<br> 

            <br><br>
            <div class="row"style="background-color:#202020">

            <div class="col-4"></div>
            <div class="col-4"></div>
            <div class="col-4"></div>
            </div>
<br><Br><br>
&copy; ILLUMONOPOLY LLC. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. 
<br><br><Br> 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delegate this for all buttons with internal href. An example with separate function to load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadMainContent('home');

    $('body').delegate('.yourInternalLinks', 'click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        loadMainContent($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});

function loadMainContent(page) {
    $('#main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');
}
```

Now you must just add "yourInternalLinks" class to links on other pages. 
With delegate, it will also work on new buttons loaded dynamically from other pages.

Comment: this didnt work for me. I still was redirected to another page saying "The requested URL /services was not found on this server." @lukasz tkacs

Comment: @DigiGodHymself sorry, I forgot about preventDefault :) Check updated code

Comment: This Definitely worked. Thank You very much now my progress can continue to making my website great.... @lukasz Tkacz